# import .fbx animation from blender to unity cause weird position and rotation

Tags: animation, export, unity, .fbx

i made some animations in blender and exported to .fbx but when i import them to unity some action clips have problem.

---

**I have read similar situations (answers, community, stackoverflow, ...)**
i realized that blender and 3ds max are using constant animation FPS but unity has decimal values in FPS. and this makes problem for me.

---

**FOR EXAMPLE**
i have shotgun reload animation that shell goes into weapon from frame 10 to 20 and from frame 20 to 29 it remains there and in frame 30 (just 1 frame) i reset position.but in unity from frame 29 to 30 takes about 0.05seconds and it shows that shell returns back.(i want to return immediately)

---

**Ways have been tried**

1. blender exporter settings (simplify = 0, sampling rate = 0.1, and any other part in settings)
2. unity (turn off resample curve, reduce keyframe, and lots of other settings)
3. unity (change time settings in project settings)
4. set interpolation mode to constant in blender
5. export 1 animation per file in blender

but none of these ways worked for me. please guide me.

Comment: In this cases the best if you make the shell as a separate object (if you use armature, you can easily bind it to a bone in Unity) and turn off the model while it flies in unwanted locations.

Comment: What happens if you don't reset it in the last frame and make the animation start over automatically, but pause on the 1. frame (Animation Editor).

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue importing my fbx from Blender to Unity. So what I did was to change the framerate from 30 fps to 29.97 inside Blender.
Then when I imported to Unity all worked good to me.